# how to construct a char array from pointer values with char, int and float types (C)

Tags: c

Im new to c and could use some help.

I am trying to output a text file using the fputs command, however I need to input a complete string to the fputs function which i dont have. I have about 6 arrays and I want to put the [i] th entry of each array into the string that is used in the fputs function.

There is one arry of characters and multiple arrays of ints and floats.

at the moment i have my various arrays and i am trying to make all of the [i]th into one array which i can send to the fputs function

eg the string I need has : {array1[i] array2[i] array3[i] etc...}

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: clarity

complier errors:
assignment from incompatible pointer types
passing argument one of fputs from incompatible pointer type.

Comment: What have you written so far? Your explanation as well as question title are kind of confusing (to me, at least).

Comment: everything i have written has failed compilation

Comment: perhaps posting some code and compile errors would help us help you

Comment: It sounds like you do not really want to use `fputs` but instead you want to use `fprintf`.

Comment: i need to output to a text file, can i do that with fprintf?

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/3/fprintf <-- rtfm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `sprintf()`.

```
char buf[256];
sprintf (buffer, "%d %d %d", array1[i], array2[i], array3[i]);
```

If you have too many `array[]`, you can use a for loop then  use `strcpy` and `strcat`to make the final `buf` which you can use in `fputs`.

Comment: thanks, that looks much better than what i was trying to do, and thanks to mah for suggesting fprintf, i wasnt aware of a print style function  that could output to a text file.